# Running jar file with no preinstalled Java on Mac machine

Tags: java, macos, wrapper, embedded-resource, portable-executable

Running jar file with embedded Java. No preinstalled java in the Mac machine.

I need to run a jar file in Mac OS X, where there is no Java installed. I have downloaded the portable Java for Mac. But can't able to run that from shell command. Please help me to run the jar using portable, embedded Java.

Answer (score 0):

What error are you getting? Does your shell script include a JAVA_HOME variable or another variable of that sort?

Such a variable would have to be set to point to the instance of java that you have installed, assuming you have the correct version required by your application.

Answer (score 0):

without a JRE on the machine, you CANNOT run a .jar file.  You'd have to use some sort of tool (ie. Launch4j) to create a native binary.  Most of these tools will create a native executable which embeds the JVM (dll, so, etc...) and use C/C++ code to initialize a jvm instance.  Once the jvm is initialized, it can run your code.

http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/